# Updating individual sql databases inside Joomla

Tags: joomla

My work website is running on Joomla 2.5 (yes, I know it needs to be updated) and recently somehow the virtuemart module was updated, resulting in a slight glitch. Now, when hovering over the Virtuemart button in the back end menu, the dropdown menu is not there, and when I click on the VM button it takes me where I need to go, but there is about 200 lines of text now that needs to be scrolled past before I can access the actual VM menu.

I have a full sql database backup from prior to the update, but I just want to know if I can just roll back the update of the module without affecting the listings within VM? I have a feeling the answer is no, so I have pinpointed anything that has been added since the issue and exported the sql table, but can I execute the full backup and then drop the individual tables in afterwards?

Attached is a pic of the text that has appeared...

Please help.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fxqX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Joomla backend as super administrator.

In the main menu select Site -> Global Configuration, then click on the “Server” tab and look for the Error Reporting parameters (these options should appear in the “Server Settings” group).
Set the Error Reporting setting to “None” and click on “Save” to store the changes.

These steps will no longer see that kind of error